# I keep getting the same error when running Angular CLI commands

Tags: command-line, node.js

No matter what command I try to run in Node.js cmd, I keep getting the same error.

I uninstalled and installed Node.js three times, I added system variables, I tried every single command (`npm update`, `npm uninstall`, `npm install`, `npm cache clean`). The `node_modules` folder doesn’t exist `AppData\Roaming\npm\`, I dont know if its supposed to be like that. I just cannot run any command, it always shows me an error with `BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"`.

Can anyone help me?

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus 
Repository Manager"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mwojciec\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08- 
29T11_15_46_940Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It's a text based error, please include the error as text. I don't get why you included the first error in the screen if you're having trouble with npm. In your example there are three distinct errors and each one has a differnt cause so they're not the same errors. Please expand your answer with the errors as text and include details about what you actually tried rather than just stating "you have tried some things".

Comment: I hope now its better

Comment: I think I messed up something when I tried to downgrade angular cli version. Now Im not able to use it at all. If there is a way to reset it completely, I would definitely do that but I've tried deleting everything and reinstalling it few times and it didnt work